# How to place a div that sticks to the bottom of the video and is responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I am trying to place a div below a video and can't figure out what the best way is. I want to stick it to the bottom of the video and make it responsive. I want the div to stay at the same place on tablet/mobile screen too.

Here is what I have for now: https://codepen.io/luca099/pen/xxOwogo

```
    <div class="myBlock">
    
        <div id="set-height"></div>
    
        <video id="v0" tabindex="0" ,="" autobuffer="" preload="" poster="https://www.agoria.be/brug-tussen-uw-bedrijf-en-technologische-vooruitgang/img/firstFrame.jpg">
          <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm">
        </video>
    
      </div>
    
      <div class="divBelowVideo">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id.</p>
</div>
    
    .myBlock {
      margin-top: 80px !important;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    #v0 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #set-height {
      display: block;
      height: 80vh !important;
    }
    
    video {
      display: block;
      height: 600px;
    }
    
    .divBelowVideo {
      position: inherit;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 2% 4%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: red;
      outline: none !important;
    }
    
    .divBelowVideo {
      width: 90%;
      padding: 2% 4%;
    }
    
    .divBelowVideo .row {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: What is the javascript for in your codepen?...

Comment: It plays the video when you scroll (code from: https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/)

Comment: You can use a `container` `div` element to wrap the video AND the div and set that `container` to a `fixed` `position`. I'll suggest an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
  var frameNumber = 0, // start video at frame 0
            // lower numbers = faster playback
            playbackConst = 50,
            // get page height from video duration
            setHeight = document.getElementById("set-height"),
            // select video element         
            vid = document.getElementById('v0');
        // var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // jquery option


        // Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
        function scrollPlay() {
            var frameNumber = window.pageYOffset / playbackConst;
            vid.currentTime = frameNumber;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}

body {
  background-color: #eeedf5;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.myBlock {
  margin-top: 80px !important;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

video {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom-video{
  text-align: center;
position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
}
.bottom-text{
  position: relative; 
  left: -50%; 
  border: dotted red 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://acdn.be/_lib/bootstrap/agoriabootstrap_4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Ly2Bg/tgKeO6mK4rBkayaR8JkXojczLjXdTrLreT7rgywL1zzyyw28IhCwDjnxmJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="myBlock">


    <video id="v0" tabindex="0" ,="" autobuffer="" preload="" poster="https://www.agoria.be/brug-tussen-uw-bedrijf-en-technologische-vooruitgang/img/firstFrame.jpg">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm">

    </video>
      <div class="bottom-video">
    <div class="bottom-text">
      I am some centered shrink-to-fit content! <br />
      tum te tum
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  

</body>

</html>
```

You can play with the CSS to style and change your bottom DIV position as you wish.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution

Codepen: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/rNLOXJe

```css
body {
  width:100%;height:450vh;margin:0:padding:0;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:flex-start;flex-direction:column;background:lightgray;
}

.c {
  display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:flex-start;flex-direction:column; position:fixed;
}

.c div {
  background:pink;width:100%;height:300px;margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="c">
    <video id="v0" tabindex="0" ,="" autobuffer="" preload="" poster="https://www.agoria.be/brug-tussen-uw-bedrijf-en-technologische-vooruitgang/img/firstFrame.jpg">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm">
      </video>
    <div>some div content here
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```